# Transition Image from Top to bottom in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to Transit my Images from Top to bottom direction. Right now it is transit from bottom left to top.

### HTML

```
<header>
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/paresh/image/upload/v1464936481/imgpsh_fullsize_aab4vm.png"><br/>
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/paresh/image/upload/v1464936481/imgpsh_fullsize_aab4vm.png"><br/>
<img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/paresh/image/upload/v1464936481/imgpsh_fullsize_aab4vm.png"></header>
```

### JS

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

### CSS

```
header{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  line-height: 108px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity : 0;
}

header.sticky {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  opacity : 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

body{
  height:1000px
}
```

Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ezNZQV

Answer (score 1):

Add `padding-left: 20px;` to `header` like on the `header.sticky`. To animate from top to bottom add `bottom:0;` to `header`.

**The Code (https://jsfiddle.net/6kbcp54m/1/):**

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

```css
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  line-height: 108px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity : 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  bottom:0;
}
header.sticky {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  opacity : 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
body {
  height:1000px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/paresh/image/upload/v1464936481/imgpsh_fullsize_aab4vm.png"><br/>
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/paresh/image/upload/v1464936481/imgpsh_fullsize_aab4vm.png"><br/>
  <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/paresh/image/upload/v1464936481/imgpsh_fullsize_aab4vm.png">
</header>
```

Comment: I put left padding but it is coming from bottom. I want it from Top

Comment: I want to start Animation from Top

Answer (score 0):

Just update the CSS to this.

```
header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity : 1;

}

header.sticky {
  top:300px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  opacity : 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
```

This may help you. I have removed the line-height. And just given the top position.